# Dynamic linq expression for EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to write some dynamic linq expression for my EF app.

I have an enum that represents a type:

```
public class MyEntity {
  public int? One { get; set; }
  public int? Two { get; set; }
  public int? Three { get; set; }
  // other fields..
}

public enum MyType {
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}

public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, int?>> GetItem(MyType myType) {
  switch(myType) {
    case One: return (e) => e.One;
    case Two: return (e) => e.Two;
    case Three: return (e) => e.Three;
    default: throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Depending on the type, I want to perform queries against it. So for example, I want to see if my type column equals to a certain value:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, int?>> EqualsValue(MyType myType, int value) {
  return Expression.Equal(GetItem(myType), Expression.Constant(value));
}
```

This is giving me a compiler error that it can't cast from BinaryExpression to Expression>. Is there a better way to do this?

UPDATE:

I would like to use it in the EF like: `ctx.MyEntities.Where(EqualsValue(myType, value)).Where(u => u.UserID == userID)` so the return type has to be `Expression<Func<MyEntity, int?>>`.. I need it to work for Linq to SQL as well as EF DataService.

Comment: It should be `public static BinaryExpression` right?

Comment: I would like to use it in the EF like: `ctx.MyEntities.Where(EqualsValue(myType, value)).Where(u => u.UserID == userID)` so the return type has to be `Expression<Func<MyEntity, int?>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, int?>> EqualsValue(MyType myType, int value) {
  return (e) => GetItem(myType)(e) == value;
}
```

Comment: this will execute the first part and compare it to the second part. if you're trying to find 2 records in a database of 1MM rows whose value for One=1, this will probably not work..

Comment: This will not "execute the first part". It will return an expression that will compare `e.One`, `e.Two` or `e.Three` depending on myType _but e depends on the dynamic input e_ to the expression that is returned...

Comment: It won't compile. It says method name expected. This is what I have: `return ( e ) => GetLinkType( linkType )( e ) == instanceID;`